# Will latches occur in sequential logic in verilog

Tags: verilog

This is a basic question but it seems to lack of clear explanation to me.

In many of code examples,one style to write FSM output is

```
assign a = (current_state==DONE)?1:0;
```

I confuse this with definition of latches. Will this combinational logic infer latches as "a" holds its previous value if current_state != DONE?  It seems no warnings from my compiler.

sometimes, i would have

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
if(reset)
  a<= 1'b0;
else
  if(current_state == DONE)
    a <=1'b1;
end
```

This is certainly a sequential logic(tho my output does not depend on my chains of past input) and a would keep its previous value until my control signal current_state == DONE.I would guess this logic will synthesize to a mux to the input of a flipflop.

so  if in the 2nd case that I actually have a clocked FSM, i would have my mux with FSM states output as the select signal input.
Until now, can i say anything that is not combinational logic will not generate any latches?

However,when i have a structure like the following,

```
always@(posedge DCO or posedge reset or posedge enable)
begin
    if(reset)
    begin


    end

    else if(enable)
    begin           

    end 
    else 
    begin
    end
end
```

I get a warning in my FPGA that i have inferred a latch with control signal enable.

Why?

My enable changes based on another state machine for example,

```
assign enable = (pcurrent_state == START)?1:0;
```

Moreover, we have unintentional latches and intentional latches. but design rule basically says to avoid latches to avoid timing arches. Can someone give some examples of where intentional latches should be used in design rather than clock gating example?

Plus,

> The output of all the storage elements (flip-flops) in the circuit at any     given time, the binary data they contain, is called the state of the circuit. The state of a synchronous circuit only changes on clock pulses. At each cycle, the next state is determined by the current state and the value of the input signals when the clock pulse occurs.(from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_logic)

This sounds like describing a mealy machine to me rather than a typical sequential logic. My simplest sequential logic does not need my output change determined by my current_state

Thank you for any help. I am doing this coding everyday and reading its definition but it seems that i am confusing myself without discuss with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in parts:

The given `assign` statement will not infer a latch as `a` does not retain it's value. It will be `1` if `current_state == DONE` and otherwise be `0`. So it's pure combinational logic.

The second block of code implements a flip-flop with synchronous reset and only loads itself with `1'b1` if `current_state == DONE` so there is retention in that code. This code shouldn't generate a latch due to the edge sensitivity on a single clock.

The last block would be difficult for any synthesis tool to handle due to the sensitivity on serveral signals, which is not common in hardware. Moreover, if say `enable` is asserted but not an edge when a positive edge of `DC0` comes along, the code would have the body of the `else if (enable)` run, thus simulating some sort of latching behavior. Synthesis tools generally allow for a single clock and single reset to be specified in the sensitivity list of an `always` block to indicate a flip-flop with asynchronous reset. While Verilog certainly allows for more complicated sensitivity lists, their physical meaning gets complicated quickly, thus inferring latches. In most designs, you shouldnt ever need these complex sensitivity lists are you are then getting into asynchronous design for which most synthesis tools are not well suited on a behavioral level. FPGA tools especially are poor at asynchronous elements and even latches as the logic cells in the fpga to which the design must be mapped are designed specifically for synchronous designs using flip-flops; that's how fpgas are implemented.

Finally, in non-fpga designs, it is sometimes desirable to use latches if edge sensitivity isn't required, as latches are physically smaller and can allow a design to be smaller, faster and more power efficient in some cases. However, you need to have a firm grasp on what you are designing and understand potential trade offs and timing requirements when doing so. Here's an example of when a latch is a useful element: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/255009/what-is-application-of-latch-in-vlsi-design

Comment: thanks. the part about the sensitivity list explains a lot my book does not have. I have that enable mainly because i want to repeat my operation again from the start once i reached a specific state. I sort of tried and invented writing it this way by saving efforts to come up with another state... i guess it doesnot work that well. typically my reset is a button but my enable is a pulse that will be high only one cycle at a specific state. i am making a control signal my reset...